# prettier-vscode is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'Json'-files

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I'm unable to use prettier-vscode as a formatter for JSON files. It seems the extension does not register it as a valid default formatter. How can I fix it or is it bug?

`prettier-vscode is configured as formatter but it cannot format 'Json'-files`

Extension:

```
Name: Prettier - Code formatter
Id: esbenp.prettier-vscode
Version: 9.0.0
```

Errors:

[image: Change Default Formatter]

[image: Selection of Formatter]